# getNotification().getBody() Fails

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to extract the message from google firebase notification message.

here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
{

    Log.d("FROM", "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom() );
    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}
```

the `remoteMessage.getFrom()` returns the correct value while `remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()` crashes with the following log:

```
.example.mturky.testfirebase W/dalvikvm: threadid=16: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4199ccf8)
05-29 18:26:09.886 15436-15583/com.example.mturky.testfirebase W/dalvikvm: threadid=16: uncaught exception occurred
05-29 18:26:09.887 15436-15583/com.example.mturky.testfirebase W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-29 18:26:09.887 15436-15583/com.example.mturky.testfirebase W/System.err:     at com.example.mturky.testfirebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived(MyFirebaseMessagingService.java:31)
05-29 18:26:09.888 15436-15583/com.example.mturky.testfirebase W/System.err:     at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzo(Unknown Source)
05-29 18:26:09.888 15436-15583/com.example.mturky.testfirebase W/System.err:     at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzn(Unknown Source)
05-29 18:26:09.888 15436-15583/com.example.mturky.testfirebase W/System.err:     at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzm(Unknown Source)
05-29 18:26:09.888 15436-15583/com.example.mturky.testfirebase W/System.err:     at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb$2.run(Unknown Source)
05-29 18:26:09.888 15436-15583/com.example.mturky.testfirebase W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
05-29 18:26:09.889 15436-15583/com.example.mturky.testfirebase W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
05-29 18:26:09.889 15436-15583/com.example.mturky.testfirebase W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
05-29 18:26:09.889 15436-15583/com.example.mturky.testfirebase W/dalvikvm: threadid=16: calling UncaughtExceptionHandler
05-29 18:26:09.890 15436-15583/com.example.mturky.testfirebase E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-4-thread-1 
Process: com.example.mturky.testfirebase, PID: 15436
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.mturky.testfirebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived(MyFirebaseMessagingService.java:31)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzo(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzn(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzm(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: You are getting a NullPointerException - probably `remoteMessage` is `null` or `remoteMessage.getNotification()` returns `null` and so calling `.getBody()` raises `NullPointerException `.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla not null because it returns the "from" value

Comment: But that is what your error log is saying: `java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.mturky.testfirebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived(MyFirebaseMessagingService.java:31)` - please check the specific line.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla yes I know, thats why I dont understand where the problem is

Comment: Perhaps you should add a log statement for `remoteMessage.getNotification()` and see what this prints out - my suspicion is that perhaps this is NULL.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla line 31 is the line where "getNotification().getBody" exists

Comment: how are you sending the message? are you using your own server or the firebase console?

Comment: @DiegoGiorgini my own server.

Comment: getBody is only available if you are setting the option notification: { body: "my body"} when you send the message. If you are sending a data payload you should be using the method getData()

Comment: @DiegoGiorgini .. Thanks a lot, that was the trick :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To expand on my comment posted under the question:

`remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()` is only available if you are sending a **notification-message**. Either using the firebase console or the server-api with
payload = `{ "notification" : { "body" : "my body"} }`

if you are sending a **data-message** like `{ "data" : { "mykey" : "myvalue"} }` then on the client you should use the method: `remoteMessage.getData()`

Comment: useful..!! can u please tell me how to display only body of the data fetched from "remoteMessage.getData()" method. Currently I am getting the whole payload as a notification in my app like this:{time=01-08-2016 12:35:22, message=demo message}

Answer (score 4):

```
sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
```

- this is for Developer console default push notification.

You should use

```
sendNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
```

- this is for custom push from any server, "message" denoted by server side.

Comment: Worked for me..Thank You very much : ) : ) : )

Answer (score 1):

Your post json object should look like below

Headers:

```
Content-Type : application/json
Authorization: key=API KEY
```

JSON Object

```
{

    "notification": {
        "title": "Title for the message",
        "body": "message content here"
    },
    "to": "registration id"
}
```

and use below line to call showNotification method as below in java.

```
showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().put("","message"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: (By @DiegoGiorgini):

getBody is only available if you are setting the option notification: { body: "my body"} when you send the message. If you are sending a data payload you should be using the method getData()

Answer (score 0):

```
  showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().put("","message"));
```

This will work, if a notification come to server side not console.

Comment: showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().put("","message"));

Answer (score 0):

```
 $message = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registrationIDs,
        'data' => array(
                "message" => $messageText,
                "id" => $id,
        ),
     'notification' => array(
                "body" => "body of notification",
                "title" => "title for notification",
        )
    );
```